# Alert message after submit and validation page in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a dynamic action doing the below ,
Submit page ,
Successful Alert message,
Log out and redirect to another website (www.google.com),
 And I  have two  required item in page.

When pressed the button and the item is null ,the successful Alert message appears and after that the system shows the error (the item is required). How can I show the successful alert message only when  the process and validation are done without errors ,and when ok is pressed in the alert message redirect to website and log out from the sessions

Comment: It appears that those items aren't required after all (if you want to ignore the warning). So set them to be non-required.

Comment: No the item it's required but when submit page the alert message appears before validation error ,  because  that how I can change the alert don't appear when item is null.

Comment: that mean how i can stop alert message and only appear when successfully process and validation

Comment: It sounds like you do not need a dynamic action. Just have your button action to be submit page and create a branch to do the redirect to the other site. That is an easier approach and much cleaner.

Comment: I know,  but success message not appear because the redirect to onther website (I have a link in  website when  click on it ,redirect to public page to  fill your data , after press finish return to web site), because that I need dynamic  alert message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways you could approach this. You're currently using a mix of Dynamic Actions and page-level validations and processes that aren't going to play well together. I suggest you move all the logic to Dynamic Actions. Here are step by step instructions to do what I think you're trying to do. You can learn from this and then integrate what you want back to your solution.

1. Create a new blank page. Mine was page 17. You'll need to update references to "P17" with your page number if it's different. Disable the page level attribute **Warn on Unsaved Changes** to prevent prompts before the redirect to Google.
2. Add a new HTML region to the page.
3. Add a new item to the region. Set **Name** to **P17_FIRST_NAME** and leave the default **Type** of **Text Field**.
4. Add a new item to the region. Set **Name** to **P17_LAST_NAME** and leave the default **Type** of **Text Field**.
5. Add a new item to the region. Set **Name** to **P17_RESULT**, **Type** to **Hidden**, and **Value Protected** to **No**. This item will be used to transfer messages from the server to the client via Ajax.
6. Add a button to the region. Set **Name** to **RUN_PROCESS** and **Action** to **Defined by Dynamic Action**.
7. Create a new Dynamic Action that fires when the button is clicked. The easiest way to do this is to right-click the button and select **Create Dynamic Action**. Set the **Name** to **RUN_PROCESS clicked**.
8. Select the **Show** action that was created by default for the Dynamic Action. Set **Action** to **Execute PL/SQL Code** and copy-paste the following code into the **PL/SQL Code** attribute.

   ```
   declare

     l_result_obj json_object_t := json_object_t();
     l_errors_arr json_array_t := json_array_t();
     l_error_obj  json_object_t;

   begin

     if :P17_FIRST_NAME is null
     then
       l_error_obj := json_object_t();

       l_error_obj.put('pageItem', 'P17_FIRST_NAME');
       l_error_obj.put('message', 'First Name is required.');

       l_errors_arr.append(l_error_obj);
     end if;

     if :P17_LAST_NAME is null
     then
       l_error_obj := json_object_t();

       l_error_obj.put('pageItem', 'P17_LAST_NAME');
       l_error_obj.put('message', 'Last Name is required.');

       l_errors_arr.append(l_error_obj);
     end if;

     if l_errors_arr.get_size() > 0
     then
       l_result_obj.put('status', 'error');
       l_result_obj.put('errors', l_errors_arr);
       :P17_RESULT := l_result_obj.to_string();
       return;
     end if;

     null; -- do "success" processing here

     l_result_obj.put('status', 'success');
     l_result_obj.put('message', 'Hi ' || :P17_LAST_NAME || ' ' || :P17_LAST_NAME || 
       '! You will now be redirected to Google.');

     :P17_RESULT := l_result_obj.to_string();

   end;
   ```

   As you can see, the validations are now being done inside the process. The PL/SQL code is making use of the JSON types introduced with Oracle 12.2. If you're on an older version of the database, you can adapt the code to use APEX_JSON instead.
9. While still in the **Execute PL/SQL Code** action, set **Items to Submit** to **P17_FIRST_NAME,P17_LAST_NAME** and **Items to Return** to **P17_RESULT**. This is how you can transfer values from the page into session state before the process executes and then back to the page after the process finishes executing.
10. Create a new Dynamic Action that fires on the Change event of P17_RESULT. The easiest way to do this is to right-click the item and select **Create Dynamic Action**. Set the **Name** to **P17_RESULT changed**.
11. Select the **Show** action that was created by default for the Dynamic Action. Set **Action** to **Execute JavaScript Code** and copy-paste the following code into the **Code** attribute.

    ```
    var result = JSON.parse($v('P17_RESULT'));

    apex.message.clearErrors();

    if (result.status === 'error') {  
      for (var idx = 0; idx < result.errors.length; idx++) {
        result.errors[idx].type = 'error';
        result.errors[idx].location = ['page', 'inline'];
        result.errors[idx].unsafe = false;
      }

      apex.message.showErrors(result.errors);
    } else if (result.status === 'success') {
      apex.message.alert(result.message, function(){
        apex.navigation.redirect('https://google.com');
      });
    }
    ```

    The JavaScript code takes the result from the process and either displays error messages or an alert. I'm using `apex.message.alert` instead of `apex.message.showPageSuccess` because the former supports a callback when the message is dismissed. When the message is dismissed, `apex.navigation.redirect` takes the user to Google.

Here's what it should look like in the end:

[image: Dynamic Action based processing]

I hope there's enough information here for you to understand what's going on. Let me know if you have any questions. You'll find the documentation for `apex.navigation` and `apex.message` here: https://apex.oracle.com/jsapi

P.S. Here's an example of what the PL/SQL code would look like using APEX_JSON.

```
declare

  l_error_count pls_integer := 0;
  l_result_obj  clob;

begin

  apex_json.initialize_clob_output;

  apex_json.open_object();

  apex_json.open_array('errors');

  if :P17_FIRST_NAME is null
  then
    l_error_count := l_error_count + 1;
    apex_json.open_object();

    apex_json.write('pageItem', 'P17_FIRST_NAME');
    apex_json.write('message', 'First Name is required.');

    apex_json.close_object();
  end if;

  if :P17_LAST_NAME is null
  then
    l_error_count := l_error_count + 1;
    apex_json.open_object();

    apex_json.write('pageItem', 'P17_LAST_NAME');
    apex_json.write('message', 'Last Name is required.');

    apex_json.close_object();
  end if;

  apex_json.close_array();

  if l_error_count > 0
  then
    apex_json.write('status', 'error');
    apex_json.close_object();

    :P17_RESULT := apex_json.get_clob_output();
    apex_json.free_output;
    return;
  end if;

  null; -- do "success" processing here

  apex_json.write('status', 'success');
  apex_json.write('message', 'Hi ' || :P17_LAST_NAME || ' ' || :P17_LAST_NAME || 
    '! You will now be redirected to Google.');
  apex_json.close_object();

  :P17_RESULT := apex_json.get_clob_output();
  apex_json.free_output;

end;
```