# I have a problem with a system I am developing in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on developing an online exam system for the university using Oracle Apex,
I have developed the most part of the system and have a problem showing the exam in front of the student,
Tables used in the exam section:
- **Test**
- **Question**

### - **Answer**

This is a picture of the relationship between the tables:

### [image: The image]

I need to display the question that is in the question table and below it are four options,
The first choice, second choice, and so on ...
After the choice, I need to compare the choice made by the student with the answer that is in the answer schedule.
This process is repeated five times, this is the total questions for each exam.
Then display the result.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207866/discussion-on-question-by-bin-magdy-i-have-a-problem-with-a-system-i-am-developi).

Answer (score 0):

As with all things in programming, there are many different approaches one could take depending on the requirements. I'll show you one approach given what we've discussed so far.

Given the following tables and data:

```
create table test (
    id    number generated by default on null as identity  
          constraint test_id_pk primary key,
    name  varchar2(255)
);

create table question (
    id         number generated by default on null as identity  
              constraint question_id_pk primary key,
    test_id    number
              constraint question_test_id_fk
              references test on delete cascade,
    question   varchar2(4000),
    ch1        varchar2(4000),
    ch2        varchar2(4000),
    ch3        varchar2(4000),
    ch4        varchar2(4000),
    correct_ch number constraint question_correct_ch_cc
              check (correct_ch in (1,2,3,4))
);

declare

  l_id number;

begin

  insert into test (name) values ('Math') returning id into l_id;

  insert into question (
    test_id,
    question,
    ch1,
    ch2,
    ch3,
    ch4,
    correct_ch
  ) values (
    l_id,
    'What is 1+2?',
    '3',
    '2',
    '4',
    '1',
    1
  );

  insert into question (
    test_id,
    question,
    ch1,
    ch2,
    ch3,
    ch4,
    correct_ch
  ) values (
    l_id,
    'What is 10*0?',
    '10',
    '0',
    '1',
    '100',
    2
  );

  insert into test (name) values ('Science') returning id into l_id;

  insert into question (
    test_id,
    question,
    ch1,
    ch2,
    ch3,
    ch4,
    correct_ch
  ) values (
    l_id,
    'How many planets are there?',
    '10',
    '7',
    '9',
    '8',
    4
  );

  insert into question (
    test_id,
    question,
    ch1,
    ch2,
    ch3,
    ch4,
    correct_ch
  ) values (
    l_id,
    ' What is the biggest planet in our solar system?',
    'Jupiter',
    'Earth',
    'Mars',
    'Pluto',
    1
  );

end;
/
```

The following should work:

1. Create a new blank page. Set **Name** to **Tests**. My page number defaulted to 29, you may need to adjust the page number in what follows.
2. Add a new region to the page. Set **Title** to **Tests**, **Type** to **Classic Report**, and **Table Name** to **TEST**.
3. Right-click **Columns** under the **Tests** region, then select **Create Virtual Column**. Click the **No Link Defined** button for **Target**. Set **Page** to be one higher than the current page (30 for me). Under Set Items, put **P30_TEST_ID** in the **Name** column and **&ID.** in the **Value** column of the same row. Set **Clear Cache** to **30**, then click **OK**. Set **Link Text** (under Target) to **Take Test**. If you run the page, you should see a report of the tests with a link to the test page (it will not work het).
4. Return to the builder and create another blank page. The **Page Number** should be one higher than the previous page (30 for me). Set **Name** to **Question**.
5. Add a new region to the page. Set **Title** to **Answer the following question**.
6. Add a new item to the region. Set **Name** to **P30_TEST_ID** and **Type** to **Hidden**.
7. Add another item to the region. Set **Name** to **P30_QUESTION_ID** and **Type** to **Hidden**.
8. Add another item to the region. Set **Name** to **Question** and **Type** to **Display Only**.
9. Add another item to the region. Set **Name** to **P30_CHOICES** and **Type** to **Radio Group**. Under List of Values, set **Type** to **SQL Query** and copy-paste the following into the **SQL Query** field:

   ```
   select val d,
     choice_num r
   from question
   unpivot (val for choice_num in (ch1 as '1', ch2 as '2', ch3 as '3', ch4 as '4'))
   where test_id = :P30_TEST_ID
     and id = :P30_QUESTION_ID
   ```

   Disable **Display Extra Values** and **Display Null Value** under the SQL Query field.

   This unpivot will turn the columns into rows so it works with the Radio Group. The user will see the text of the choice but the choice number (1-4) will be returned.
10. Right-click **Before Header** under **Pre-Rendering** and select Create Process. Set **Name** to **Init page** and copy-paste the following code into the **PL/SQL Code** field.

    ```
    declare

      l_question_rec question%rowtype;

    begin

      if :P30_QUESTION_ID is null
      then
        select id
        into :P30_QUESTION_ID
        from question
        where test_id = :P30_TEST_ID
        order by id
        fetch first 1 row only;
      end if;

      select *
      into l_question_rec
      from question
      where id = :P30_QUESTION_ID;

      :P30_QUESTION := l_question_rec.question;
      :P30_CHOICES := null;

    end;
    ```
11. Add a button to the region. Set **Button Name** to **NEXT_QUESTION**.
12. Under the processing tab, right-click **Processing** and select **Create Process**. Set **Name** to **Select next question** and copy-paste the following code into the PL/SQL Code field:

    ```
    select id
    into :P30_QUESTION_ID
    from question
    where test_id = :P30_TEST_ID
      and id > :P30_QUESTION_ID
    order by id
    fetch first 1 row only;
    ```
13. At this point, if you return to the previous page and run it, you should be able to select a test and see the first question. You should also have the ability to select from the available choices and use the Next Question button to see the next question.

    [image]

This is a minimum viable example. I've not provided you, up to this point, with a means of validating answers - though I could do that if you want. I suggest you try it first using the techniques I describe here: [Alert message after submit and validation page in oracle apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920469/alert-message-after-submit-and-validation-page-in-oracle-apex/60008537)

I've also not accounted for lots of other things: security, don't show the next question button when you're on the last question, etc. I've not done any of that because I'm just trying to give you an idea of how things could work. There will surely be many things you'll want to tweak according to your requirements.

Finally, after having played with this a little, I probably would add a third table for the choices/answers - though it wouldn't work as you had it defined before. It would just store the answers in rows rather than columns which make them a bit easier to work with relationally (no need to unpivot, for example).

Comment: thank you sir ,
I will work on it.
I will need some additions, such as adding time to the question, saving the answer that the student performs in the score table, then calculating the total scores and printing the result after the last question